# how to push value , spesific by index in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have data array of objec . in this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Soil 
            [method] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 10 mm 
            [method] => 
        )
)
```

here I receive input index , and value ..

```
$index = 1;
$method = 'junior'
```

I want to push the data based on the index data I received

result

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Soil 
                [method] => 
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [nama_barang] => 10 mm 
                [method] => junior // push by index 1
            )
    )
```

How to ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$yourArray[1]['method'] = 'junior'
```

In PHP, you just assign the value to the array. The path keys are automatically created if they do not exist.